# Setting JAVA_HOME so Cordova in Visual Studio picks it up

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, java-home

I'm puling my hair out over this one. I can't get Visual Studio 2015 to reliably pick up my JAVA_HOME directory. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I have tried clearing the cordova cache, re-starting the pc and none of it seems to work.

[image: Screen shot of system vars]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't get Visual Studio 2015 to reliably pick up my JAVA_HOME directory.

You can override JAVA_HOME of VS by `Tools->options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Environment Variable Overrides`:

[image]

Comment: I did have that set correctly but for some reason refreshing the value got it working again. How odd, must be some sort of bug in VS.

Comment: I ended up removing and re-installing jdk 182 for the same issue.